# Having Components of Objects Disable once far enough away

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I am making a infinite arcade style game and when the player starts the game, balls will be randomly generated across a map, and the players goal is to hit them and get points.

Anyways, if the player is far enough away, I want to disable the collider and sprite to make the game run a bit smoother. Or if the ball will delete itself, and then respawn when the player gets closer.

Sorry if this is a bit confusing. Also, the balls are instantiated if that changes anything.

Comment: Hi, what have you tried so far and what doesn't work?

Comment: I haven’t really tried anything, I was looking some stuff up, but didn’t really apply. I’m kind of looking for a starting point.

Comment: one thing you could try: Vector3.Distance(playerPosition,ballPosition)>YourDistanceThreshold

Comment: Sounds good, but I need more help with the deleting\disabling part, maybe something where it saves positions, and then delete when out of range.

Answer (score 1):

If you start from the beginning, you don't need to be too concerned about optimization, because we will do it later, after you have done your game. You need to focus on game design and also game mechanic. If your need to spawn object, you need to know about `Instantiate` method. You want to make balls spawned randomly each second, you need to now about `InvokeReapeating` method. Or more advanced, you will have to learn about object pooling and much more. Just keep learning from the beginning, not to think complicated. When you have done the basic, just move on something bigger, yeah

Comment: Thank you for the help, I will look more into InvokeRepeating.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Destroy(GameObject) to get rid of a game object that is no longer necessary.

```
    Destory(gameObject); // this destroys the game object that the script is attached to
```

There are a number of tutorials out there for destroying game objects under various conditions such as going off the playable area.

Seems the simplest way to approach what you're looking for is to check the distance to the player from the Ball, and if greater than a threshold, self destruct. This would need to be done from a script on the Ball, and you would need a reference to the Player object

```
    const float Threshold = 25f; // Some distance away from the player
    public GameObject Player; // Drop the player on here from the editor, or find using a tag, name, etc.

    void Update()
    {
        // Get the absolute distance between the object and the player
        var distanceToPlayer = Mathf.Abs(Vector3.Distance(transform.position, player.transform.position)); 
        // If greater than threshold, goodbye
        if (distanceToPlayer > Threshold)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
```

Now, if you want to respawn the object once the player returns to the area that could be handled by your spawn manager by keeping track of the state of the objects it has spawned, event listeners, etc.